# Android MediaRecorder - how to make it vbr?

Tags: android

Is it possible to setup MediaRecorder to record h264 with variable video bitrate (VBR) in given bounds? How can I do that?

Comment: Hi did you find the ans?

Comment: nope, sorry... no one knows

Comment: Sad to hear that :( (after 6 years)